# memcached and IIS manager with windows 2008

Tags: memcached, iis

I have memcached (c:\memcached) running on port 11211 and I have a problem configuring IIS manager

I created a site in IIS manager binded to port 11211 and if I have memcached running and try and start the site it says "the process cant access the file because it is being used by another process"

If I stop memcached and start the site in IIS (and enable directory browsing) I can access the directory structure http://localhost:11211 ok, if I then try and start memcached it errors with error 1053 "could not start the memcached server on local computer"

I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here! just cannot figure out how I can use IIS and memcached together.

[edit]I should add that I need other servers to be able to access memcached[/edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything in IIS to enable memcached. As long as it's running and you can telnet to port 11211 on that server from other servers you are good. So, make sure your firewall config allows those servers to 11211, then just follow the documentation for your chosen client library.